# Scope of karate.callSingle() when having multiple Runner executions

Tags: karate

During the upgrade of an automation project to the latest Karate version, we noticed a different behaviour of `karate.callSingle()` in the Karate version 1.2.0 compared to the old Karate version 0.9.6.

According to the documentation, `karate.callSingle()` ensures that a routine *"runs only once"*. However, there is no clear statement about the scope in which the statement *"runs only once"* is true, so I don't really know if the old behaviour (in Karate 0.9.6) just worked by accident - or if there is a bug in the Karate 1.2.0.

**This is our scenario:**

We run our tests as JUnit 5 Parallel Execution and use the Cucumber-Reporting test report, so our test class looks very similar to https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/DemoTestParallel.java . There is one exception: When creating the Cucumber-Reporting `ReportBuilder` object, we add so called `classifications` (which are key-value pairs) to the `Configuration` object, because we want to display some information (artefact name, version number) about the software under test in the report. To read out the version number, we're calling a feature file, that returns the version.

As a result, the unit tests contains two `Runner` executions: `Runner.path().parallel()` to execute all tests - and `Runner.runFeature()` to execute only the feature that returns the version information, so that it can be passed to the Cucumber-Report:

```
class DemoTestParallel {

    @Test
    public void testParallel() {
        Results results = Runner.path("classpath:demo")
                .outputCucumberJson(true)
                .karateEnv("demo")
                .parallel(5);
        generateReport(results.getReportDir());
        assertTrue(results.getErrorMessages(), results.getFailCount() == 0);
    }

    public static void generateReport(String karateOutputPath) {
        Collection<File> jsonFiles = FileUtils.listFiles(new File(karateOutputPath), new String[] {"json"}, true);
        List<String> jsonPaths = new ArrayList<>(jsonFiles.size());
        jsonFiles.forEach(file -> jsonPaths.add(file.getAbsolutePath()));

        final Map<String, Object> versionResult = Runner.runFeature("classpath:demo/versionInformation.feature", null, true);

        Configuration config = new Configuration(new File("target"), "demo");
        config.addClassifications("demoArtefact", versionResult.get("version"));

        ReportBuilder reportBuilder = new ReportBuilder(jsonPaths, config);
        reportBuilder.generateReports();
    }

}
```

In karate-config.js, we execute a feature with `karate.callSingle()`, as we want to run it only once:

```
var order = karate.callSingle('classpath:demo/reusableOrder.feature@createSuccessfulOrder', config);
config.orderId = order.id;
```

In Karate version **0.9.6**, `karate.callSingle()` was also ensured during multiple `Runner` executions. So in the scenario above, `reusableOrder.feature@createSuccessfulOrder` was executed only **once**.

In Karate versions **1.2.0**, `karate.callSingle()` is *not* ensured during multiple `Runner` executions. So in the scenario above, `reusableOrder.feature@createSuccessfulOrder` gets executed **twice** (once during `Runner.path().parallel()` and another time during `Runner.runFeature()`).

**Is it a bug or a feature?**

As I mentioned, I don't know if this is a bug or a feature :)

In case it's a feature, I would be happy about suggestions how to avoid to have `reusableOrder.feature@createSuccessfulOrder` executed twice.

What I had in mind but didn't work in our case:

- Change the `Runner.runFeature()` statement to pass `evalKarateConfig = false`, to avoid executing karate-config.js . However, we need karate-config.js execution, as it defines some environment specific variables, that are needed for all feature files.
- Define `callSingleCache`, to read the result of `reusableOrder.feature@createSuccessfulOrder` a cache. However, defining `callSingleCache` broke other tests (don't know why, didn't investigate further).

I am happy about any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot to unpack in your question, but just skimming - yes the "scoping" of `callSingle()` to a `Runner` instance is intentional. The reason is it should be possible for teams to run 2 `Runner` instances in parallel without blocking.

So my suggestion is please stuff everything you have into a single `Runner`. If it means refactoring your tests, I think that's the right approach. For example, what I would do is have `reusableOrder.feature` write some file to the file-system, which you can then read in your reporting routine.

No other suggestions come to mind other than the extreme option of writing your own Java utility that wraps `reusableOrder.feature` - but ensures it returns data only once, so build your own cache within the active JVM.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!

We'll try to build our own simple cache that we can use to store information during feature/scenario execution and then read out when building the Cucumber Report.